# CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long while using Spring Security

Tags: java, grails, groovy, spring-security-rest

I am using JDK v.1.8, Grails v.3.3.10. I am trying to implement some of the endpoints of my app as rest and remaining as normal web pages URL. So to achieve this added below lines in build.gradle file

```
    `compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:2.0.0.M2'`
    `compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.0'`
```

After doing when I was trying to run the grails app I was getting below exception

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\java.exe" (in directory "D:\myprojectfolder"): CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
> at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

So to resolve above I used below line in build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id "com.virgo47.ClasspathJar" version "1.0.0"
}
```

and it has solved my issue.